# Search in SQL Database (C# UWP)

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, uwp

I'm new in developing for Windows 10.
I have database with customers.

I make connecting to it like this

```
using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("Database= milanoold_db;Data Source=144.76.133.122;User Id=milanoold_u;Password=sK5PvCDP; SslMode=None; CharSet=utf8"))
```

I want to make search of customer via his telephone if I found him, I need to write all info about this client to Console.

Table has this fields - id,name, mob, adress, birthday, email.

I need to make search by mob.I try to use this query

```
 searchButton1.Click += delegate
 {
      connection.Open();
      MySqlCommand createCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM reg_user WHERE mob LIKE '%+380675090373%'", connection);
      createCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
 };
```

How I can display all fields of this customer to Console?

Thank's for help.

**UPDATED**

Also I have this error when tap on search button

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message='windows-1252' is not a supported encoding name. For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method.
Parameter name: name
  ParamName=name
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Globalization.EncodingTable.internalGetCodePageFromName(String name)
       at System.Globalization.EncodingTable.GetCodePageFromName(String name)
       at System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(String name)
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.CharSetMap.GetEncoding(DBVersion version, String CharSetName)
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlField.SetFieldEncoding()
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlField.SetTypeAndFlags(MySqlDbType type, ColumnFlags flags)
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetColumnData(MySqlField field)
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetColumnsData(MySqlField[] columns)
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetColumns(Int32 count)
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ResultSet.LoadColumns(Int32 numCols)
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ResultSet..ctor(Driver d, Int32 statementId, Int32 numCols)
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
       at Milano.NewOrder.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0(Object <sender>, RoutedEventArgs <e>)
  InnerException:
```

Comment: First Load all results to DataTable. Loop Through all columns in Datatable and write to Console.

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace and exception details for the listed error?

Comment: Edited post with details @EJoshuaS

Comment: Exception details and full stack trace imply, that you post **text**, not screenshots. Screenshots are nice to look at, but undiscoverable in text searches.

Comment: Added error text@IInspectable

Comment: I think I need to convert query to utf-8?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use ExecuteNonQuery for a SELECT, you want to use DataReader. See below for instructions:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx

ExecuteNonQuery will only return the number of rows impacted by the command. It's intended for SQL commands that do *not* return values (such as INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE).

Comment: So as I understand, I download variables from table and there make search?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're asking. Your SQL query is searching the database, your C# is only sending the query to the database and retrieving the results.

Comment: Can you show me some code for searching in database?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What's wrong with your SELECT statement? Have you tried running it in a separate tool to see if it works? Does it retrieve the values you expect? (If not, please edit the question to describe the expected results and show the actual results).

Comment: It retrieve value that I expected. And display row with this value.

How I can show this row in Console?

Comment: If you know that the query is getting the value(s) you expect, you can just use DataReader to retrieve the rows and then use String.Format and Console.WriteLine to write the values.

Comment: Like this  MySqlCommand createCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM reg_user WHERE mob LIKE '%+380675090373%'", connection);
                        MySqlDataReader reader = createCommand.ExecuteReader();
                       Debug.WriteLine(reader.ToString());
?

Comment: Very similar to that; you'll have to loop through the rows returned by Reader. Also, you'll probably want to use Console.WriteLine rather than Debug.WriteLine.

Comment: I have error about encoding. I write about it in my post.

Comment: UWP don't have Console.WriteLine as I know.